# Roles/permission security of home rolled version versus gem in RoR web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I'm about to launch my first website and I'm concerned about security. The top two role/permission gems I keep seeing come up are cancancan and pundit for RoR web apps. Is there a significant advantage of those packages versus my own home rolled version?

To give the run-down of my version: I have a user, role, and user_role model, where user_role is the join-table to contain the many-to-many relationship. I assign/change roles via the roles_controller with

```
def change
  @role = Role.find(params[:id])
  @user = User.find params[:user_id]

  # if user is assigned to be a student, delete all other roles
  if @role.name == 'student'
    @user.roles.each do |role|
      @user.roles.delete Role.find(role.id)
    end
  end

  # if user is assigned to be a teacher, delete student (if present)
  if @role.name == 'teacher' && @user.has_role?('student')
    @user.roles.delete Role.where(name: 'student')
  end

  @user.roles << @role if request.patch?
  @user.roles.delete @role if request.delete?

  redirect_to @user
end
```

And the controller has `before_action :admin_user` so that only admins can perform these actions. In addition, I have various before_actions for each role within different controllers based on roles, logged in users, and correct users. Are there some possible security issues I need to be aware of with this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage is that they are not your home rolled one-off. CanCanCan and Pundit have been used in scores of apps and have been battle tested and have a huge community both working on them and eying them for flaws - can you honestly say you will be doing the same for your solution down the line?

Also CanCanCan and Pundit are authorization libraries - they can be used to build role based authorization - but roles are not a built in part of either.

If you want a gem which is role library take a look at [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) which makes it pretty simple to create roles which are linked to users and resources. It can be used with CanCanCan, Pundit or any other authorization lib.